# Entropy for TLS 1.2: how much is needed for linux servers?

Tags: tls, entropy

I am trying to fix issues with a server where the server keeps freezing up and needs to be restarted. I recently started hearing about entropy and it importance to secure tls keys in linux. The one thing I haven't found in my research is, how much is needed/how to increase entropy on a linux server for TLS 1.2.

I believe this is where the issue is coming from. It started to appear when we were implementing TLS 1.2 and the randomness might not be high enough.

Have done some research on the topic, talked to a few other higher level developers but no one seems to be ale to point me in the write direction.

Comment: Generally 128 bits of entropy  is enough to start a CSPRNG. Usually the `/dev/(u)random` should be seeded by the OS during the startup phase. If you have an embedded system you should check which entropy sources are available. If you have a virtualized system then you probably want to install the additional client tools as that should generally seed the random generator (especially useful if you have multiple instances of the same VM).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, I used the ale to put me in the write direction (see your last sentence) ;)

Comment: Headless servers often suffer from a lack of entropy.  If you want to increase real entropy available you can usually use rngd and have it get entropy from the CPU (e.g. RDRAND).  This will add data from the CPU to the kernel's entropy pool. See https://linux.die.net/man/8/rngd for more information.

Comment: This has a lot of information on the topic: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/186086/is-always-use-dev-urandom-still-good-advice-in-an-age-of-containers-and-isola

Comment: I believe the correct solution on Linux is to use getrandom. This will definitely fix "application freezes after running for a while" because it will not block again after enough entropy is available. It will however block if there is not enough entropy available on startup which is necessary to have good randomness.

Answer (score 1):

While it's quite possible that any daemon (I mean MySQL in particular since my employer had trouble with it before we increased our RAM capacity) can cause a freeze, let's focus on entropy source for PRNGs since the topic of our site is cryptography.

The common practice is to use the `/dev/urandom` device for practically all of the randomness source.

- On Linux, this special device does not block at all - not even when the "estimated" entropy of its seed material is low.
- On BSDs, `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` behaves identically, as their developers believe that any properly designed PRNG *algorithm* can meet the demand even when just bare-minimum entropy is fed.

So the cryptographic advice to your problem, is to switch to `/dev/urandom` in your configuration.

References:

- [FreeBSD man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=random&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+13.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html)
- [Linux man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=random&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=Debian+8.1.0&arch=default&format=html)

Also, keep updating software regularly (I convinced my employer to do so once a month), because if this is indeed a bug, it may get fixed in some version.

Answer (score 1):

The proper interface to use on Linux is `getrandom`, which is available in most Linux distros these days.  The interface will block until the CSPRNG is initialized on startup (unless `GRND_NONBLOCK` is specified) and never again.

That ensures that you have at least 256 bits of entropy on the system, which is enough to generate all the keys you could possibly need.  The system will continually reseed the CSPRNG with new entropy as it goes along as well.  Note that making sure the CSPRNG is seeded on Linux is very easy if you have a hardware RNG like RDRAND or RDSEED and you've configured `CONFIG_RANDOM_TRUST_CPU` in your kernel (most distros do).

On FreeBSD, `getrandom` is also available, and you can use `getentropy` or `arc4random` on any of the BSDs.  (Technically, those are also available on Linux, but only in more recent versions of glibc.)  To my knowledge, the BSDs by default ensure the OS CSPRNG is seeded appropriately on startup, provided writable media exist.  See the `random(4)` page for your BSD for details.

On most varieties of Unix, `/dev/urandom` can be used as well, but on Linux it doesn't guarantee that the CSPRNG has been appropriately seeded.  That's why using `getrandom` or `getentropy` is preferred.

On Windows, `RtlGenRandom` is the right interface.

Note that if your system is hanging after the machine has been up and serving TLS requests for a while, then it isn't a lack of entropy, because all major operating systems continue to serve data from the system CSPRNG after it's initially seeded.  As mentioned, 256 bits of entropy is sufficient to generate a virtually unlimited amount of random data on the system (especially considering the fact that you'll reboot now and again for kernel security updates), so there's no need to block once correctly seeded.